# System plugin with DRCsim launch files

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The launchfiles used to start up the DRC worlds don't allow for us to add a system plugin.  How would I do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2368/system-plugin-with-drcsim-launch-files/) by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In atlas_utils/scripts, there are several scripts that invoke gazebo with plugins (for example [run_gazebo](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/bc8a56f09eff03fc79f909a9f67467bc23a0dd3d/ros/atlas_utils/scripts/run_gazebo?at=default) calls `gazebo -s libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so`. For the moment, you can edit these scripts, but there is a better fix in the works in [drcsim pull request #198](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/198).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2013-05-08**:
I am trying to run a system plugin (`gazebo_ros_api_plugin`) with standalone gazebo so that /clock will be published to ROS. Can you please explain how I can run "run_gazebo" with empty.world. Thank you